# ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(157)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I create a simple Qt project(built with msvc-2017 kit) to test QWebEngineView:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWebEngineView * view=new QWebEngineView();
    view->load(QUrl("https://www.google.com"));
    view->show();
}
```

But the app reports error:

```
ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(157)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
```

and soon crashes. No webpage is opened in the view.
What is the problem?